# How to do speech recognition using MFCC method in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, speech-recognition, mfcc, filter-bank

I'm developing a Speech Recognition engine for recognizing few (10-14) isolated words. I'm using MFCC (Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficient) method and doing it using MATLAB. I'm referring a research paper and a website and other sources. I have mentioned the links below. Following are the main problem I'm facing:

1. Knowing whether the sampling frequency of 44100Hz that I have chosen is correct or not?
2. Whether the lower frequency=300Hz and upper frequency=8000Hz that is chosen to calculate Mel Filter Bank Matrix is correct or not?
3. Whether the frame-size=256, and no.of filter banks(coefficients)=20 that I have chosen is suitable for my application?
4. Whether pre-emphasis filter used is good?
   Or should I use butterworth filter?
5. Is normalisation of samples required before processing/ after filtering? Which normalisation technique should I use in that case?

CODE STRUCTURE:

RUN the MainRunning.m file. (Used to run code for the TRAINING SET once, and then the test samples)

SevenStep.m contains the code for training

SevenStepTestSample.m contains the code for testing

[I have put my code in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_XzDuHAGiQGNi16NlF3WGdkR28)

[Research Paper I'm referring is in this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_XzDuHAGiQGcmp5VDNkeFd3Wk0)

[Reference website from where I studied calculation of Mel-Filter-Bank other than the research paper and other sites](http://practicalcryptography.com/miscellaneous/machine-learning/guide-mel-frequency-cepstral-coefficients-mfccs/)

Please suggest the error that I'm getting and the optimal upper frequency, lower frequency, frame-size, no. of filter banks for my application? How do I find the Hmatrix in my code correctly?(Mel Filter bank). Also do suggest any other errors, if any.

Thanks a lot in advance.

CODES:

MainRunning.m

```
    wordArray= {'begin', 'continue', 'exit', 'move', 'save', 'undo'};
% //NOT USING THESE REMAINING WORDS NOW :, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'};
SevenStep();
for j=1:6 %for all words in database
    ADDITION=0;
    disp(strcat('CHECKING FOR THE WORD: ',upper(wordArray{j})));
    for i=1:15 % each word has 15 samples for testing the accuracy of system
        [Value1]=SevenStepTestSample(strcat('C:\Users\Ray\Documents\BE Project\Phase-III\FreshAudioSamples\test\',wordArray{j},num2str(i),'.wav'));
        Result1=strcmpi(Value1,wordArray{j});
        %Result2=strcmpi(Value2,wordArray{j});
        ADDITION=ADDITION+((Result1));
    end
    fprintf('%s\t%d\n',upper(wordArray{j}),ADDITION); %Used to display no. of words correctly identified out of 15
end
```

SevenStep.m

```
function SevenStep()
    tic
    %-----------------------------------------------------------------INITIALISATION---------------------------------------------------------------%

    path_start='C:\Users\Ray\Documents\BE Project\Phase-III\FreshAudioSamples\';
    path_end='.wav';

    alpha=0.97;
    fs=44100; %frequency at which I have sampled my recorded samples
    pad_length=120064;
    numSamplesOfEachWord=30; %in database of samples
    numOfWords=6;
    frame_length=256; %How to choose an appropriate frame-size?
    no_of_frames=pad_length/(int32(frame_length/2)); %since overlap is 50%
    low_freq=300; %lower frequency for calculation of mel frequency filter bank (I'm unable to choose a correct one, and find the criteria for choosing it)
    high_freq=8000; %upper frequency for calculation of mel frequency filter bank (I'm unable to choose a correct one, and find the criteria for choosing it)
    no_of_coeffs=20;    % This is no. of Mel-Filter banks to create. how to choose a approriate value for this?

    %{

    fnm = 'C:\Users\Ray\Documents\BE Project\Phase-III\trifbank.mat'; 
    m1= matfile(fnm);
    H=m1.H;

    //Method 2 which I used to calculate when my Mel Frequency Filter Bank
    (given below) was probably not working correctly 

    %}

    %--------------------------------------------------PRE-PROCESSING FOR MEL FILTER BANK CREATION-----------------------------------------------%


    low_linear=2595*log10(1+(low_freq/700));
    high_linear=2595*log10(1+(high_freq/700));
    band_length=(high_linear-low_linear)/(no_of_coeffs+1); 

    MelArray(no_of_coeffs+2,1)=zeros(); %to store mel frequencies to calculate mel frequency filter bank
    LinearArray(no_of_coeffs+2,1)=zeros();  %to store linear frequencies to calculate mel frequency filter bank
    FreqArray(no_of_coeffs+2,1)=zeros();    %to store frequency array to calculate mel frequency filter bank
    %{
THIS ARRAY MAY HAVE WRONG VALUES DUE TO SELECTION of WRONG PARAMETERS LIKE low_freq, high_freq, frame_length (frame-size), no_of_coeffs (no. of filter banks). THIS IS MAJOR REASON BEHIND GENERATION OF NaN values in HMatrix
    %} 
    HMatrix(no_of_coeffs,frame_length)=zeros();  %Hmk Matrix/ Filter Bank
                                                 %I'M VERY DOUBTFUL OF THE
                                                 %VALUES GENERATED BY THIS
                                                 %FILTER BANK

    MelArray(1)=low_linear;
    MelArray(no_of_coeffs+2)=high_linear;
    LinearArray(1)=low_freq;
    LinearArray(no_of_coeffs+2)=high_freq;
    FreqArray(1)=floor((int32(frame_length)+1)*LinearArray(1)/fs);
    FreqArray(no_of_coeffs+2)=floor((int32(frame_length)+1)*LinearArray(no_of_coeffs+2)/fs);



    for m=1:no_of_coeffs
        MelArray(m+1)=MelArray(m)+band_length;
        LinearArray(m+1)=700*((power( 10,MelArray(m+1)/2595))-1);
        FreqArray(m+1)=floor((int32(frame_length)+1)*LinearArray(m+1)/fs);
    end


    % THE MOST DOUBTFUL PART i.e. MEL FREQUENCY FILTER BANK MATRIX CREATION

    %---------------------------------------------------------PROBABLE ERRONEOUS PART------------------------------------------------------------%
    % I'M GETTING NaN values in this matrix probably due to choosing
    % incorrect parameters for  like upper freq, lower freq, frame-size, no.of filter banks, sampling frequency etc.

    for k=1:frame_length
        for m=1:no_of_coeffs
            if(k<FreqArray(m))
                HMatrix(m,k)=0;
            elseif (FreqArray(m)<=k && k<=FreqArray(m+1))
                HMatrix(m,k)=(k-FreqArray(m))/(FreqArray(m+1)-FreqArray(m));
            elseif(FreqArray(m+1)<=k && k<=FreqArray(m+2))
                 HMatrix(m,k)=(FreqArray(m+2)-k)/(FreqArray(m+2)-FreqArray(m+1));
            elseif (k>FreqArray(m+2))
                 HMatrix(m,k)=0;
            end
        end
    end
    %--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


    SM(no_of_frames,frame_length)=zeros();
    FVector(no_of_frames,no_of_coeffs,numOfWords*numSamplesOfEachWord)=zeros();
    LogFiltered(no_of_frames,no_of_coeffs)=zeros();
    FinalResult(no_of_frames,no_of_coeffs)=zeros();
    WindowValues=hamming(frame_length);

    wordArray= {'begin\', 'continue\', 'exit\', 'move\', 'save\', 'undo\'};
    % //NOT USING THESE REMAINING WORDS NOW : 'a\', 'b\', 'c\', 'd\', 'one\', 'two\', 'three\', 'four\', 'move\a1\', 'move\a2\', 'move\a3\', 'move\a4\'};

    %{
    //NOT USING THIS NOW
    filenaming = 'C:\Users\Ray\Documents\BE Project\Phase-III\Normalising.mat';
    m = matfile(filenaming);
    Nrm=m.Nrm;
    %} 

    %------------------------------------------------------------------TRAINING--------------------------------------------------------------------% 



    for i=1:numOfWords
        for j=1:numSamplesOfEachWord

            %----------------------------------------------------------READING WORD SAMPLE---------------------------------------------------%

           SD=wavread(strcat(path_start,wordArray{i},num2str(j),path_end));
           %SD=Nrm(j+(i-1)*numSamplesOfEachWord,:);     //NOT USING THIS NOW
           %SD=NoiseFilter(SD);                         % //NOT USING THIS NOW

           %----------------------------------------------------PRE-EMPHASIS FILTER-------------------------------------------------------%
           SD=filter([1 -alpha], 1, SD);               
           %------------------------------------------------------------PADDING-----------------------------------------------------------%

           SD=pad(SD,pad_length); % function given at the end of this file

           %-------------------------------------------------------FRAMING AND WINDOWING-------------------------------------------------------%
           %----------------------------------------------------AND CALCULATING FFT OF OBATINED SAMPLES--------------------------------------------%
           SD=reshape(SD,no_of_frames,frame_length/2);

           for k=1:no_of_frames-1
              temp=fft(([SD(k,:) SD(k+1,:)]'.*WindowValues)');
              SM(k,:)=temp.*(conj(temp));

           end
           temp=fft(([SD(no_of_frames,:) zeros(1,frame_length/2)]'.*WindowValues)');
           SM(no_of_frames,:)=temp.*(conj(temp));

           %-------------------------------------------------APPLYING MEL - FILTER BANK AND LOG FILTERING--------------------------------------------%
           for h=1:no_of_frames
                for l=1:no_of_coeffs
                    LogFiltered(h,l) = log10(sum(SM(h,:).*HMatrix(l,:)));
                end
           end

           %----------------------------------------------------------APPLYING DCT---------------------------------------------------------%           

           for indexing=1:no_of_frames
              FinalResult(indexing,:)=dct(LogFiltered(indexing,:));
           end

           %---------------------------------------------------STORING TRAINING DATASET---------------------------------------------------%

           FVector(1:no_of_frames,1:no_of_coeffs,j+(i-1)*numSamplesOfEachWord)=FinalResult;

        end
    end

    save('SevenStep');   %Saving all variables to retrieve during running the program for SR
    toc
end

function p=pad(x,full_length)
    p = vertcat(x, zeros(full_length - length(x),1));
end


%{
NOT USING THIS NOW, BUT IF YOU CAN SUGGEST CHANGES IN THIS IT WOULD
APPRECIABLE

function Y=NoiseFilter(SD)
    [B, A]= butter(2,0.01); % IS THIS CORRECT FOR MY SAMPLES? 
    X= filter(B, A, SD);
    %figure; plot(SD);
    X(abs(X)< 0.01) = 0;
    %figure; plot(X);
    %X=X(find(X,1,'first'):find(X,1,'last'));
    Y=SD(find(X,1,'first'):find(X,1,'last')); % TAKING FROM ORIGINAL SAMPLE
    %figure; plot(Y);
end
%}
```

SevenStepTestSample.m

```
function [StrVal1] =SevenStepTestSample(filename)

   tic

    alpha=0.97;
    KVal=13; %The no. of values used for final comparison
    pad_length=120064;
    numSamplesOfEachWord=10;
    numOfWords=6;
    frame_length=256; %How to choose an appropriate frame-size?
    no_of_frames=pad_length/(frame_length/2); %since overlap is 50%
    no_of_coeffs=20;    % This is no. of Mel-Filter banks to create. how to choose a approriate value for this?

    wordArrayPrint= {'begin', 'continue', 'exit', 'move', 'save', 'undo'};
    % NOT USING THE REMAINING WORDS FOR NOW :'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'};   

    filenm = 'C:\Users\Ray\Documents\BE Project\Phase-III\SevenStep.mat'; % This is the storage space of training set data
    m = matfile(filenm);
    FVector=m.FVector; 
    HMatrix=m.HMatrix;
    WindowValues=m.WindowValues;

    TSM(no_of_frames,frame_length)=zeros();
    TLogFiltered(no_of_frames,no_of_coeffs)=zeros();
    TFinalResult(no_of_frames,no_of_coeffs)=zeros();

    [testSample,t1] = wavread(filename);

    %{
    WAS USING THIS FOR NORMALISATION OF VOICE SAMPLES, NOT USING IT NOW

    tt=max(abs(testSample));
    for j=1:length(testSample)
    RD(j)=(testSample(j)/tt);
    end
    testSample=RD;
    %}


    % NOT USING THIS NOW : testSample=NoiseFilter(testSample);
    testSample=filter([1 -alpha],1,testSample');
    testSample = vertcat(testSample', zeros(pad_length - length(testSample),1)); 
    testSample=reshape(testSample,no_of_frames,frame_length/2);

    for k=1:no_of_frames-1
        temp=fft(([testSample(k,:) testSample(k+1,:)]'.*WindowValues)');
        TSM(k,:)=temp.*(conj(temp));
    end
    temp=fft(([testSample(no_of_frames,:) zeros(1,frame_length/2)]'.*WindowValues)');
    TSM(no_of_frames,:)=temp.*(conj(temp));

    for h=1:no_of_frames
        for l=1:no_of_coeffs
            TLogFiltered(h,l) = log10(sum(TSM(h,:).*HMatrix(l,:)));
        end
    end

    for indexing=1:no_of_frames
        TFinalResult(indexing,:)=dct(TLogFiltered(indexing,:));
    end


    errorArray = zeros(numOfWords*numSamplesOfEachWord,1);

    for j=1:numOfWords*numSamplesOfEachWord
           errorArray(j)= mean2(abs(TFinalResult(1:no_of_frames,2:KVal) - FVector(1:no_of_frames,2:KVal,j)));
    end     

    %errorArray'


   [err, index1] = min(errorArray);

   %{
   NOT USING THIS NOW: THIS CODE IS TO CALCULATE SECOND MINIMUM ASSUMING
   THE FACT THAT NO TWO SAMPLES WILL GIVE SAME ERROR VALUE
   [err,index2] = min(errorArray(errorArray>min(errorArray)));
    if(index1<=index2)
       index2=index2+1;
     end
   %} 
   for j=1:numOfWords
    if (index1 >= (1+(j-1)*numSamplesOfEachWord) && index1 <= j*numSamplesOfEachWord)
        StrVal1=upper(wordArrayPrint{j});
        disp(StrVal1);
    end

    %{
        if (index2 >= (1+(j-1)*numSamplesOfEachWord) && index2 <= j*numSamplesOfEachWord)
            StrVal2=upper(wordArrayPrint{j});
        end
    %}
   end

       %fprintf('%s\t%s\n',StrVal1,StrVal2);
       % save('SevenStepTestSample');

  toc

end
```

Comment: This is broad for a single question. You ask "suggest the error that I'm getting". Are you referring to the output being not as expected? How does it differ from what you want? Also all the necessary code should be included in the question, not on an external link. If the code is too much for a single question, you  should try to narrow the focus of your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the output being not as expected in speech recognition. Words are wrongly being recognized. The main reason behind this wrong result is the wrong calculation of HMatrix in the code. It generates a NaN value. The reason may also be because of wrongly generating Frequency Array.
I added an external link since there were .mat files and many errors could have been possible. So, it's easy to understand for the reader if they have access to the .mat files and variables.